# Quelling Blade interaction with Sleight of Fist + Cleave

Tags: dota-2

For simplicity's sake, supposing that Ember Spirit has a Quelling Blade which deals 50% damage to non hero units, and Ember spirit has 50% cleave from whatever source, and that hypothetically Sleight of Fist does a static damage value of 100 to whatever unit it hits and this 100 damage is never reducted, if I hit a creep unit that stands beside a hero, how much **cleave damage** will the hero take?

A: 50 damage, meaning no Quelling Blade bonus damage added to cleave, i.e. creep is hit for 150 damage, but only 100 damage is accounted for cleaving purposes.

B: 75 damage, as the creep is hit for 150 damage due to the hipothetically 50% bonus damage of quelling blade.

C: None of the above.

Comment: Do you mean Sleight of Fist dealing 100 bonus damage or the total damage being 100 with the bonuses taken into account ?

Comment: The situation is described as a hypothetical situation, so the numbers were altered. That said, Sleigh of Fist, in this case, is dealing 100 total damage in every cast, disregarding enemy armor value, hero base damage, hero total damage, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is B or C depending on what you mean with 100 damage :

- If you're supposed to deal 100 damage to the creep you're about to hit for whatever reason, then Sleight of Fist doesn't matter at all and the calculation is : 100x(cleave%)x(1+quellingBladeBonus%) = 100x(50%)x(150%) = 75 damage. **The answer is B**
- If you're supposed to deal 100 damage to heroes, then the calculation is tricky and requires to know the level of Sleight of Fist you have because it deals both bonus damage to heroes *AND* 50% of normal damage to creeps. **The answer is C**

I guess your question was regarding the interaction of Quelling Blade and Cleave, and Sleight of Fist is not really necessary here as it's just a source of confusion. The answer is : **Cleave and Quelling blade do stack**, if you are late in the game and you happen to have cleave% x (1+quellingBladeBonus%) > 1 (disregarding armor) you're better off hitting creeps than heroes if you have the chance to.

Note that it's not reliable with Sleight of Fist as you don't have a lot of control over the angle you hit the creeps from.

Comment: The reason I state Sleigh of Fist is because I still am not sure about its interactions with Quelling Blade. All I know is that it does a normal physical attack every 0.2 seconds to each unit in the area with an added bonus damage of 80 in the current version, but I was not sure if Quelling Blade affected Sleight of Fist.

Comment: It does. As you said yourself, it deals a normal physical attack (with a 50% reduction that was disregarded because you said it would be 100 damage, but you should not forget about it), therefore quelling blade bonus applies

Comment: Hmm, I see. And yeah, I removed the 50% reduction to creeps to keep it simple. Thanks for the answer.